# How to print the process step by step in python?

Tags: python

I am a student who starts learning python last month. I am doing my homework and I think I am close to my answer. I want to repeat the process before the final output is 123 and I want to print each steps changing rows. This is the code that I use. I can print the proper 1st row but repeating this process is hard for me.

```
x = list(input())
o = 0
e = 0
t = len(x)

if int(x[0]) % 2 == 0:
    e += 1
if int(x[0]) % 2 != 0:
    o += 1

i = 0
while i < (t - 1):
    i += 1

    if (int(x[i]) % 2) == 0:
        e += 1
    if (int(x[i]) % 2) != 0:
        o += 1

a = (f'{e}{o}{t}')

print(a)
```

If I use two whiles there comes an error message saying "crashed while testing."

Comment: Use a debugger: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: As a hint, you could replace the while loop with `for idx, elem in enumerate(x):`. Then what's the input provided? Add *print* statements inside the loop. Check: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: which parameter you want to print?